# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode

When I try to open this project using Xcode (4.3.2 version), Xcode itself is crashing. So I have tried to run this application using 4.2.1 version. Still I am unable to run the app because of exit code 1 error.

Here is the crash report
4.3.2

```
Process:         Xcode [2754]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.3.2 (1177)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1177000000000000~6
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 7171108
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [124]

Date/Time:       2012-05-16 11:10:04.196 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50d)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          85377 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           24
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  169728 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   22
Anonymous UUID:                      AFF60601-8342-44D3-996E-A9C618654CF5

Crashed Thread:  12

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4E2002
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-1197/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTargetBuildContext.m:1890
Details:  Assertion failed: [filePath isAbsolutePath]
Object:   <PBXTargetBuildContext: 0x4025f1ae0>
Method:   -setHeadermapToolInvocation:forFilePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x402ffc440>{name = (null), num = 16}
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000110b65c8f -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsCore)
  1  0x000000010d224635 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000110b5d248 -[PBXTargetBuildContext setHeadermapToolInvocation:forFilePath:] (in DevToolsCore)
  3  0x0000000110bade52 -[XCCompilerSpecification computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:outputDirectory:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x0000000110c4884e -[XCBuildRuleDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:withOutputDirectory:additionalProperties:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x0000000110c41647 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) _computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:inTargetBuildContext:processedPaths:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x0000000110c41d25 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForFilePath:ofType:forBuildFileReference:usingBuildRule:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x0000000110c422c3 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForBuildFileReference:inTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x0000000110c36c0c -[XCBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x0000000110c43ab0 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesForAllBuildFileReferencesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x0000000110c44450 -[XCSourcesBuildPhaseDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x0000000110bb111e -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x0000000110c324d3 -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesInTargetBuildContext:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x0000000110b54f81 -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x0000000110b66c15 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x00007fff90ccdf4c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 16  0x00007fff90ccdde4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 17  0x0000000110b66010 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x00007fff90ccdf4c __invoking___ (in CoreFoundation)
 19  0x00007fff90ccdde4 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation)
 20  0x0000000110ba97e1 -[XCInvocationQueue _processNextInvocationInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 21  0x0000000110ba9c48 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 22  0x00007fff915e074e -[NSThread main] (in Foundation)
 23  0x00007fff915e06c6 __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 24  0x00007fff91e168bf _pthread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)
 25  0x00007fff91e19b75 thread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib)
```

4.2.1 exit code 1 error report:

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OMH.app/OMH normal i386
    cd /Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol -F/Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/CrashReporter -filelist /Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/build/iPhoneMH.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OMH.build/Objects-normal/i386/OMH.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC /Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/../iPhone-Debug-iphonesimulator/libfunambol.a -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30103 /Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20UI.a /Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20UINavigator.a -framework AddressBookUI -framework MessageUI -framework MediaPlayer -framework ImageIO -framework CoreLocation -lsqlite3 -weak_framework EventKit -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AddressBook -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CrashReporter -o /Users/deepthi/OMH-Funambol/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OMH.app/OMH

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Without the actual error message, there is no way anyone can really help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your commandline tools have not been installed.

From the online docs for Xcode:

Command-Line Tools Are Optional
The command-line tools are not bundled with Xcode 4.3 by default. Instead, they can be installed optionally using the Components tab of the Downloads preferences panel.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html